# Hadoop: Error when running the example ShowFileStatusTest

Tags: hadoop

everyone.I am new to hadoop and so interested in it.I have read a book tilte "Hadoop:The Definitive Guide".And i think i am encounter a problem when i try to run to example ShowFileStatusTest in approximately pages 60.
The problem is that it always has a failure test for fileStatusForFile function. No file has been created in either hdfs file system or local file system.So it gives the message "File does not exist"
Well , here i display some of log message i get

```
> fileStatusForFile(ShowFileStatusTest)
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist:
> /home/hadoop/setenv.sh    at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1122)
>   at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
>   at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
>   at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114
```

and i try to figure out the messages,but i failed.Why it use fs.defaultFS?And why it is hdfs://127.0.0.1:0.It really confuses me as i have check two files,core-site.xml and core-default.xml. It sets fs.defaultFS to file:// and fs.name.default to hdfs://master:9000:

```
   18/04/30 18:40:40 INFO namenode.NNStorageRetentionManager: Going to retain 1 images with txid >= 0
18/04/30 18:40:40 INFO namenode.NameNode: createNameNode []
18/04/30 18:40:40 INFO impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
18/04/30 18:40:40 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
18/04/30 18:40:40 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system started
18/04/30 18:40:40 INFO namenode.NameNode: fs.defaultFS is hdfs://127.0.0.1:0
```

here is my code:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
//import static org.hamcrest.*;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Test;


import java.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
public class ShowFileStatusTest{
    private MiniDFSCluster cluster;
    private FileSystem fs;  
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws IOException {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
//      conf.set("fs.default.name","hdfs://master:9000");
        if(System.getProperty("test.build.data")==null) {
            System.setProperty("test.build.data","/tmp");
        }
        cluster = new MiniDFSCluster(conf, 1, true, null);
        fs = cluster.getFileSystem();
        OutputStream out = fs.create(new Path("/dir/file"));
        out.write("content".getBytes("UTF-8"));
        out.close();    

    }
    @After
    public void tearDown() throws IOException{
        if( fs!=null ){fs.close();}
        if( cluster!=null ) {cluster.shutdown();}
    }

    @Test(expected=FileNotFoundException.class)
    public void throwsFileNotFoundForNonExistentFile() throws IOException{
        fs.getFileStatus(new Path("no-such-file"));
    }

    @Test
    public void fileStatusForFile() throws IOException{
        Path file = new Path("/home/hadoop/setenv.sh");
        FileStatus stat = fs.getFileStatus(file);
        assertThat(stat.getPath().toUri().getPath(),is("/home/hadoop/setenv.sh"));
        assertThat(stat.isDir(),is(false));
        assertThat(stat.getLen(),is(7L));
//      assertThat(stat.getModificationTime(),
//          is(lessThanOrEqualTo(System.currentTimeMillis()))
//          );
        assertThat(stat.getReplication(),is((short)1) );
        assertThat(stat.getBlockSize(),is(64*124*1024));
        assertThat(stat.getOwner(),is("hadoop"));
        assertThat(stat.getGroup(),is("supergroup"));
        assertThat(stat.getPermission().toString(),is("rw-r--r--"));
    }

}
```

uhhhh,not a native speaker ,so I am sorry for my poor English.But i will try to make you understand. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try making these changes in your code and running the test again:

Line 27: `OutputStream out = fs.create(new Path("/dir/file"));` to      `OutputStream out = fs.create(new Path("/home/hadoop/setenv.sh"));`

Line 54: `assertThat(stat.getBlockSize(),is(64*124*1024));` to `assertThat(stat.getBlockSize(),is(128*1024*1024L));`

(If test fails because of owner) Line 55: `assertThat(stat.getOwner(),is("hadoop"));` to       `assertThat(stat.getOwner(),is("<os-user-running-the-test>"));`

Comment: hi, the change of code  "assertThat(stat.getBlockSize(),is(128*1024*1024L))" really help solve my problem. Thanks for your help ~~~

Answer (score 0):

i think i have solved my problem. Here is my final code.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
//import static org.hamcrest.*;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Test;


import java.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
public class ShowFileStatusTest{
    private MiniDFSCluster cluster;
    private FileSystem fs;  
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws IOException {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
//      conf.set("fs.default.name","hdfs://master:9000");
        if(System.getProperty("test.build.data")==null) {
            System.setProperty("test.build.data","/tmp");
        }
        cluster = new MiniDFSCluster(conf, 1, true, null);
        fs = cluster.getFileSystem();
        OutputStream out = fs.create(new Path("/dir/file"));
        out.write("content".getBytes("UTF-8"));
        out.close();    

    }
    @After
    public void tearDown() throws IOException{
        if( fs!=null ){fs.close();}
        if( cluster!=null ) {cluster.shutdown();}
    }

    @Test(expected=FileNotFoundException.class)
    public void throwsFileNotFoundForNonExistentFile() throws IOException{
        fs.getFileStatus(new Path("no-such-file"));
    }

    @Test
    public void fileStatusForFile() throws IOException{
        Path file = new Path("/dir/file");
        FileStatus stat = fs.getFileStatus(file);
        assertThat(stat.getPath().toUri().getPath(),is("/dir/file"));
        assertThat(stat.isDir(),is(false));
        assertThat(stat.getLen(),is(7L));
//      assertThat(stat.getModificationTime(),
//          is(lessThanOrEqualTo(System.currentTimeMillis()))
//          );
        assertThat(stat.getReplication(),is((short)1) );
        assertThat(stat.getBlockSize(),is(128*1024*1024L));
        assertThat(stat.getOwner(),is("hadoop"));
        assertThat(stat.getGroup(),is("supergroup"));
        assertThat(stat.getPermission().toString(),is("rw-r--r--"));
    }
    @Test
    public void fileStatusForDirectory() throws IOException{
        Path dir = new Path("/dir");
        FileStatus stat = fs.getFileStatus(dir);
        assertThat(stat.getPath().toUri().getPath(),is("/dir"));
        assertThat(stat.isDir(),is(true));
        assertThat(stat.getLen(),is(0L));
    //  assertThat(stat.getModificationTime());
        assertThat(stat.getReplication(),is((short)0));
        assertThat(stat.getBlockSize(),is(0L));
        assertThat(stat.getOwner(),is("hadoop"));
        assertThat(stat.getGroup(),is("supergroup"));
        assertThat(stat.getPermission().toString(),is("rwxr-xr-x"));    
    }
}
```

Thanks for Jagrut Sharma. I have changed the key code `assertThat(stat.getBlockSize(),is(64*124*1024));` to `assertThat(stat.getBlockSize(),is(128*1024*1024L));`
and my problem solved with no failure test. Through this example, I think the main problem is that i always misunderstand the log message. When i use my old code with `assertThat(stat.getBlockSize(),is(64*124*1024));`, i always get the log message which declares a error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hamcrest.Matcher.describeMismatch(Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/hamcrest/Description;)V
```

The message really confuses me. I had no idea that it implies my fault assertion.However,  i misunderstand it and i take it as a fault of my improper use of some functions.  What's more, i take it for granted that there should be a file "/dir/file" in either local file system or hdfs due to i have no idea of the use of MiniDFSCluster in this example.Anyway, what i should do is to learn more...